# GraphQL sever responding OK to GET, but not to POST

Tags: post, http-status-code-404, response, graphql, graphql-js

My graphql server configured on Hapi is responding just fine to GET requests:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql?query={content(id:"13381672"){title,id}}

{
  "data": {
    "content": {
      "title": "Brooks Brothers Pre-Fall 2016",
      "id": "13381672"
    }
  }
}
```

However...404 using POST:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"query":"{content(id:\"13381672\"){title,id}}"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql --header "Content-Type:application/json"
{"statusCode":"404"}
```

Here is the route as configured for Hapi:

```
{
  method: ['GET', 'POST'],
  path: '/graphql',
  config: {
    handler: handlers.graphql,
    tags: [
      'graphql'
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that the payload being returned from a function in the relevant Hapi controller was empty, I adjusted same to correctly respond to a POST payload as well as a GET query string.